# NgbDropdown gets clipped by column

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

In my application I have 2 columns, left side are the controls and right side are the settings of these controls, on of the settings is set by an NgbDropdown. So I have this issue with my NgbDropdown where it gets clipped by the column next to it like so:[image]

The position is set to absolute and also tried to set the z-index higher than the left column, which didn't work. I have also tried the container="body" solution, which actually does the job but then the dropdown doesn't stick to the inputfield (floats when you start scrolling). I'm looking for either a solution with the container="body" attribute or a CSS and/or JS one to overlap the column or trigger the overflow-x when the settings column becomes too narrow

current css

```css
.dropdown-menu{
    max-width: 290px!important;
    max-height: 200px!important;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 7px!important;
    position: absolute!important;
    left:0;
    z-index: 1000!important;
}
```

current html

```html
<div class="form-group margin">
          <label for="validator">Validator <i class="mdi mdi-information" placement="bottom" container="body"></i></label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control bg text-white" name="validator" id="validator" [(ngModel)]="selected[0].validator">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <div ngbDropdown>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" ngbDropdownToggle></a>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="bg">
                      <div ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let validator of validators; let i = index">
                        <a (click)="addValidator(validator.expression)">
                          <p></p>
                          <p></p>
                        </a>
                        <div></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```